# 2D array argument to thread c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, 2d

I am trying pass 2D arrays to c++ threads. If I understood well I should do something like that :

```
double DDnx[Nx], AAnx[Nx], BBnx[Nx], CCnx[Nx],    DDny[Ny], AAny[Ny],BBny[Ny], CCny[Ny];
double n[Nx][Ny], cO2[Nx][Ny];
double DtDbDxs, Dxs2;
thread th1(&ADI_N, n, cO2, AAnx, BBnx, CCnx, DDnx, AAny, BBny, CCny, DDny, DtDbDxs, Dxs2);
```

The function ADI_N takes all these argument.

```
void ADI_N(double n[][Ny], double cO2[][Ny],
       double AAx[], double BBx[], double CCx[], double DDx[],
       double AAy[], double BBy[], double CCy[], double DDy[], double DbDtDxs, double Dxs2);
```

I have an error : No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::thread'

The point is that I would like to pass my argument by reference to ADI_N() to avoid the waist of time copying data.
Of course just putting ref() around the argument does not work

Any idea?

All the best

///EDIT///

Here is an example which compile without threading

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
#define Nx 100
#define Ny 100

void ADI_N(double n[][Ny], double cO2[][Ny],
       double AAx[], double BBx[], double CCx[], double DDx[],
       double AAy[], double BBy[], double CCy[], double DDy[],
       double DbDtDxs, double Dxs2)
{
    //do things
}


int main()
{
double DDnx[Nx], AAnx[Nx], BBnx[Nx], CCnx[Nx],    DDny[Ny], AAny[Ny],BBny[Ny], CCny[Ny];
double n[Nx][Ny], cO2[Nx][Ny];
double DtDbDxs, Dxs2;

//pass by pointer or ref the 2D matrix to the function ADI_N
thread th1(&ADI_N, n, cO2, AAnx, BBnx, CCnx, DDnx, AAny, BBny, CCny, DDny, DtDbDxs, Dxs2);
//ADI_N(n, cO2, AAnx, BBnx, CCnx, DDnx, AAny, BBny, CCny, DDny, DtDbDxs, Dxs2); //this compile

//th1.join();

}
```

Comment: What is `cO2tmp`?

Comment: Change `cO2tmp` to `cO2` and the code is okay. You have some other problem. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: I have tested on Clang and GCC, there are no error. Which compiler do you use?

Comment: I am using g++7

Comment: @user1885349: Your edit compiles, but your question is complaining about a compiler error. Please clarify exactly what your problem is.

Comment: Thanks to think about this questions. Main question is more precisly how to send a function (ADI_N) with its 2D table argument as a reference. If I give brutally the tables (n, CO2,...) to the thread it is going to copy them. This will slow done the execution of the code.